# What are gradients and how would I use them?

Tags: calculus, terminology

I keep seeing this symbol $\nabla$ around and I know enough to understand that it represents the term "gradient." But what is a gradient? When would I want to use one mathematically?

Comment: ∇ is not gradient. ∇ is the [nabla operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla_symbol), which has no meaning in and of itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The $\nabla$ (pronounced "del") is an operator, more technically.  In 3D, it (more or less) means the vector

\begin{equation}
\Big(\frac{df}{dx}, \frac{df}{dy}, \frac{df}{dz}\Big)
\end{equation}
So, if $f(x,y,z) = x^{2} + y^{3}z + sin(z)$, $\nabla f = (2x,~ 3y^{2}z,~ y^{3} + \cos z) $

It's actually a bit more subtle than that; technically it means

\begin{equation}
\Big(\frac{d}{dx}, \frac{d}{dy}, \frac{d}{dz}\Big)
\end{equation}

And when you do $\nabla f$, it's sort of like a "multiplication" of $\nabla$ and $$;

\begin{equation}
\Big(\frac{d}{dx}, \frac{d}{dy}, \frac{d}{dz}\Big)f = \Big(\frac{df}{dx}, \frac{df}{dy}, \frac{df}{dz}\Big)
\end{equation}

Only, not multiplication, but *operation*.

There are some neat properties about the del operator.  Here are a few of them:

- The most famous one is that $\nabla f$ yields the **gradient** of $f$.  That is, at any point $(x,y,z)$, $\nabla f(x,y,z)$ is the vector pointing in the direction where it is **most increasing**.  The magnitude of it is the magnitude of the increase.

  This is easier to understand with, say, a 2D $f(x,y)$.  If $f(x,y)$ represents the height of a point at $(x,y)$, then $\nabla f(x,y)$ represents the steepest incline from that point.  Or rather, if you placed a ball on that point, it would *start rolling in the opposite direction of the gradient vector*.
- Normally, for multi-dimensional functions, it is easiest to find the derivative along an axis ($x$, $y$, $z$, etc.).  With $\nabla$, you can find the derivative along any arbitrary direction by using $\nabla f . u$, ('$.$' being the dot product) and $u$ is the unit vector along the direction you are calculating.
- $\nabla$ is also used to calculate divergence (amount that vectors are "spreading out") and curl (amount that vectors are "curling up") of a vector field.

  Divergence is $\nabla . f$ (dot product), and curl is $\nabla \times f$ (cross product).

  They aren't truly "products" in the sense.  Rather, when you are calculating divergence and curl and you must do $\frac{d}{dx} . \text{(something)}$, you are actually doing $\frac{d}{dx} \text{(something)}$ or $\frac{d \text{something}}{dx}$.